# Redirect URLs with query string ?donotcache=1 for UserAgent Android

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I want to redirect my all page from static page to donotcache=1 page here is my code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Android" [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}?donotcache=1 [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

but code not working.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: page not redirecting if I use without useragent.

Answer (score 0):

Working Code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Android" [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}$1?donotcache=1 [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```